# How to store data securely using Laravel / Eloquent firstOrCreate?

Tags: php, laravel, hash, eloquent, bcrypt

I'd like to check if user exists, if not create a new entry for their user name (a gmail address)

I wish to hash the email for security, however upon every check the bcrypt salt changes, so it is determined a new user.

```
$user = user::firstOrCreate(['email' => bcrypt($googleUser['email'])]);
```

How can I keep this secure and have firstOrCreate recognise a previous user?

Comment: what is the reason for securing the email address?

Comment: Seems like the sensible thing to do! This is people's private info; last thing I want to do is make that vulnerable. The site is primarily designed for people with disabilities - some are very vulnerable to contact over email.

Comment: so move to usernames for login instead of emails a lot simpler

Comment: It's a Google Calendar application - the username might have multiple calendars (or 2 people could have the same name) - email is the only unique identifier available.

Comment: @RyanVincent - that makes some sense, however that seems 'wasteful' as I'd have to fetch all the users to see if they match - rather than searching for a single hash

Comment: @RyanVincent - I'm not storing passwords I'm afraid, just the email (as a user ID to reference other database tables) - is there not a method of keeping the salt static - I think this would achieve what I need

Comment: AH! That makes more sense.

Comment: However, I would still need to fetch ALL hashed passwords and check against them all. (right?) - as I have no other reference to the username

Comment: @RyanVincent - I'm sorry, I've not explained this well at all. The plain-text email address is not being stored. They're logged in via Oauth. I wish to store a unique identifier so I use persistent data with the user. Unfortunately, the only unique identifer I can use is their email address. I do not want to store this as plain-text, hence the attempt to hash. Unfortunately bcrypt is unsuitable as the salt changes, so I cannot match the hashed email with a pre-stored one, so the app considers them a new user.

Comment: But you can get the plain text email from somewhere? OAuth? Before looking up the user details?

Comment: Yep. I get that every time they log in. (really appreciate this by the way...)

Comment: Right - You don't have access to the user details - just the email address to do the lookup with? And that need to be 'hashed' in some way?

Comment: Here is what I do... I have a script / it could be a file, with a 'random 32 byte string stored in it'. It lives on the server outside the `document root`. You use that as the salt for your email address. use any `cryptographic hash` with that to hash the email address.That is the key you store in the database for the user data.  It will be secure. That is the key you hash with the user email to do the lookup with. It could be stored in an environment variable, config entry etc.

Comment: ok, that works, thank you. Laravel generates a unique APP_KEY in .env so I'll use that. crypt() looks suitable for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: Can you post what you finally decide to do,  as an answer, and accept it - it marks it s complete so no one wastes time on it. Was glad to assist.

Comment: ah, this isn't working either - `$user = user::firstOrCreate(['email' => crypt($googleUser['email'],env('APP_ID'))]);` the hash is still changing... perhaps `crypt()` isn't suitable. I'll explore further

Comment: use the PHP function `sha1` for now. It will get you going. Decide how secure it needs to be later.

Comment: I initially had it as an argument and then realised it made no difference - didn't think to append it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved using Laravel's auto generated `env('APP_ID')` as a static SALT and PHP's `sha1()` function

```
 $user = user::firstOrCreate(['email' => sha1($googleUser['email']).env('APP_ID')]);
```